# Discord.py slash commands expect a number input

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to ask for a number in one of my slash commands.
Thank you! :)
Code:

```
@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'leaderbord', description='Check leaderbord') 
async def slash3(interaction: discord.Interaction, number: #What is needed here?):
```

Comment: maybe inside function you should get message and use `int()` to check if it is number.

Comment: Do you know how to expect text, so i can check if its a number?

Comment: did you try `number:int`? You can also use `number:str` and later check `int(number)` in `try/except` to catch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was `number: int`
Thanks to @furas!
the right Code is:

```
@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'leaderbord', description='Check leaderbord') 
async def slash3(interaction: discord.Interaction, number: int):
```